# Attribute cy returning expected length error in D3 V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a scatter plot with the following data set:

[cyclist-data.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/cyclist-data.json)

Here is the code for the circles I am trying to create for the scatter plot:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain([minTime, maxTime]).range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0])
          .domain([0, d3.max(function(d){
            return d.Place
          })]);

chart.selectAll('.dot')
       .data(data)
       .enter().append('circle')
       .attr('class', 'dot')
       .attr('r', '3.5')
       .attr('cx', function(d){
          return x(parseInt(d.Time))
       })
       .attr('cy', function(d){
          return y(d.Place)
       })
```

However, I keep getting this error

> d3.min.js:4 Error:  attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".

Not really sure what's going wrong, because the value I am passing into my `y` function is a number (`d.Place`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `d3.max()` is missing the first parameter, i.e. the array to get the maximum value of. Accoding to the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-array#max), the correct usage will be:

> d3.max(*array*[, *accessor*]

Thus, you need to change your y-scale's definition to:

```
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0])
          .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){
            return d.Place
          })]);
```